# How to deal with id gap when your query is like from id > XX to id < XXX

Tags: sql-server

I have a large table of around 50M data. I am trying to get data with something like

```
select id,name,address,city
from table_name
where id > 50000000 and id < 50000050 
order by id;
```

But, this strategy could work only when there is no deleted data. However, In my case, I am soft-deleting data so whenever a row is deleted, its column `deleted_at` will be filled with current timestamp i.e when deleted `deleted_at is not null`.

Now, how can I tackle this situation? Please, suggest me what would be my best bet for this.

I am ready to:

- create the index with an extra column(if possible) and reorder on every deletion
- create a temp table with extra table and reorder it on every deletion
- Or same trick with view
- or some other way.

Comment: Though your question is upvoted,it is not clear,what output you are expecting.what data you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I aaume you want to extend the range of your search so it returns 50 rows even if there are gaps. Then you can use this:

```
SELECT TOP (50)
    id, name, address city
FROM table_name
WHERE id > 5000000
  AND deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY id ;
```

A partial index on `(id) WHERE (deleted_at IS NULL)` would improve efficiency.

Comment: Although, I have marked this as an accepted answer. I feel like still it will be difficult to deal with numeric pagination. Do you have any idea how to deal with numeric pagination?
For example, At first, I query from top 50 where id > 1. in case if 2 data were deleted in between 1-50 it will fetch data from 1-52. Now, for page no 2 I could fetch top 50 from id > 52. But how to find, if user decides to skip one page.